# Парсинг строки C

Tags: c++, c, парсер

Привет всем.
Есть необходимость парсить строку следующего вида: `-f 1000 -d 10 -f 90`
Необходимо такую строку спарсить (независимо от расположения аргументов), проверить значения параметров на корректность (например, это должны быть натуральные числа), и присвоить определенным переменным в коде.
Будет что-то вроде запуска с аргументами. Естественно, параметры могут быть записаны в случайном порядке, могут быть пропущены (тогда будет установлено значение по умолчанию). Понимаю, что нужно смотреть в сторону `sscanf` и регулярных выражений, но может быть у кого-нибудь уже есть готовый код. Строка записана в буффер. Спасибо.

Comment: Вполне нетривиальная задача. Готовый код, например, тут: https://github.com/cofyc/argparse

Comment: Спасибо всем за помощь! Было принято решение слегка упростить задачу, а именно - параметры будут передаваться без ключа в определенном порядке.

Answer (score 1):

если данная строка передается через аргументы командной строки, то все уже давно придумано. Для этого есть функции getopt(), getopt_long();
https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/ru/library/au-unix-getopt/

Comment: К сожалению, это не аргументы командной строки (иначе я бы использовал boost::program_option для удобства). Это будет прием строки через UART с ПК на микроконтроллер. Здесь нужно придумать подобный парсер самому, вот и решил обратиться

Comment: Ну, если приходит строка, ничто не мешает ее превратить в нечто подобное argv, и получить то что хотим.

Answer (score 1):

В gcc (и в mingw тоже) для этих целей есть вполне стандартные функции: `getopt()`, `getopt_long()`, `getopt_long_only()`. Почитать про них можно хотя бы [здесь](http://www.opennet.ru/man.shtml?category=3&russian=0&topic=getopt). Для случая Visual Studio, наверное, можно взять [этот](https://github.com/skandhurkat/Getopt-for-Visual-Studio) вариант. Правда, последнего мне нашел гугль, а сам я не пробовал его использовать (я предпочитаю gcc).

Answer (score 0):

Как-то давно я написал разборщик командной строки. И с тех пор им пользуюсь. Вот код:

Заголовочный файл comline.h :

```
#ifndef COMLINE_THIS
#define COMLINE_THIS

#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

const char comline_switch1='-';
const char comline_switch2='/';

bool comline_getswstring(int argc,char *argv[],char sw,char** s);
bool comline_getnswstring(int argc, char *argv[],int num,char** s);

template <class T>
bool comline_getswvalue(int argc,char *argv[],char sw,T* val){
char *s;
bool ret=comline_getswstring(argc,argv,sw,&s);
if(ret!=false){
stringstream st(s);
if(val!=NULL) st>>(*val);
}
return ret;
};

#endif
```

Файл кода comline.cpp:

```
#include <comline.h>

bool comline_getswstring(int argc, char *argv[],char sw,char** s){
int i;
   for(i=1;i!=argc;i++){
      if(((argv[i][0]==comline_switch1)||(argv[i][0]==comline_switch2))&&(argv[i][1]==sw)){
         if(s!=NULL) *s=argv[i]+2;
         return true;
      }//if
   }//for
return false;
}

bool comline_getnswstring(int argc, char *argv[],int num,char** s){
int n=0;
int i;
for(i=1;i!=argc;i++){
   if((argv[i][0]!=comline_switch1)&&(argv[i][0]!=comline_switch2)&&(argv[i][0]!=0)){
      if(n==num){
         if(s!=NULL) *s=argv[i];
         return true;
      }//if
      n++;
   }//if
}//for
return false;
}
```